# Defining a `required` field in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I define text field as required (with red border) in Twitter Bootstrap 3?

`required="required"` doesn't work...

```html
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
    <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 87):

Try using `required="true"` in bootstrap 3

Comment: maybe it did nothing because you let a return false or e.preventDefault in the function that handle your form submission. ie:  $('#my_button').on('click', function (e) { /* my code; */ return false; }); will prevent the required attribute to work. Just return true instead or remove the return

Comment: also note that in all cases the validation is supposed to work in the scenario where the form is actually submitted. if e.g. fields are submitted through an XHR Ajax request, I wouldn't expect the required attributes / needs-validation etc. classes to work.

Answer (score 70):

**Update 2018**

Since the original answer HTML5 validation is now supported in all modern browsers. Now the easiest way to make a field required is simply using the required attibute.

`<input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" required>`

or in compliant HTML5:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" required="true">
```

[Read more on Bootstrap 4 validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938703/cant-make-the-validation-work-in-bootstrap-4/45938912#45938912)

---

In Bootstrap 3, you can apply a "validation state" class to the parent element: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation

For example `has-error` will show a red border around the input. However, this will have no impact on the actual validation of the field. You'd need to add some additional client (javascript) or server logic to make the field required.

Demo: http://bootply.com/90564

---

Comment: Thank you. How to make input type = "email"? After entering the correct value of email => blue border?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by input type=email? Are you looking for live email validation as the user types?

Comment: Yes, I§m looking for live email validation :-)

Comment: @motorcb I think you failed to read the last comment by Skelly

Comment: @motorcb Since this fixed your problem, you should let future users know by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer (under the vote thing).  This will mark the answer as "accepted".  (And, as a bonus, it gives Skelly an extra 15 rep :))

Comment: At the time of writing, pre HTML5 validation, it was the correct answer. It is qualified with "You'd need to add some additional client (javascript) or server logic to make the field required". Thanks for the unjustified downvote.

Answer (score 6):

Check out native HTML5 form validation:

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

Answer (score 5):

Form validation can be enabled in markup via the data-api or via JavaScript. Automatically enable form validation by adding `data-toggle="validator"` to your form element.

```
<form role="form" data-toggle="validator">
   ...
</form>
```

Or activate validation via JavaScript:

```
$('#myForm').validator()
```

and you need to use **required** flag in input field

For more details [Click Here](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/)

Comment: you forgot to mention that this is not a feature of bootstrap itself, so a plugin is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If wont work in case you have something like : novalidate="novalidate" attached to your form.

Answer (score 0):

To make a field required, use `required` or `required="true"`

I think `required="required"` has been deprecated in version 3 of bootstrap.

Comment: `required="required"` is a HTML attribute and has certainly not been deprecated, especially not by bootstrap.

Comment: To me its obvious you meant the bootstrap CSS selector which styles  `required="required"` has been deprecated and not the HTML standard. yes this is correct,  the selector `input:focus:invalid, textarea:focus:invalid, select:focus:invalid` has been deprecated in version 3 of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'needs-validation' apart from form-group, it will work.

Comment: <form class="form-group needs-validation" action="index.html" method="get">