# Form not validating required fields with BootStrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that submits with empty required fields.

I'm using Twitter BootStrap with it.

I [posted this example](https://jsfiddle.net/ThiagoJourdan/h5q8q5mu/5/) in `jsFiddle`.

Maybe is just an tag issue from BootStrap, but i'm really not seeing what is wrong.

Comment: Related: [Defining a `required` field in Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19640616/2006429)

Comment: I did not know Bootstrap had built-in validation.

Comment: @Sparky Its not Bootstap who is doing it. It is HTML5. [Check these MDN docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required)

Comment: @RahulDesai, yes, I know.  That was my whole point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.

Since I have a `button` (`div`, actually) outside the form that will trigger the submit, I found my way by (quick fix) triggering a click on a hidden submit button.

The HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form class="ajaxForm">
    <div class="container col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">
               Nome
           </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control nome" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">
                CPF
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control cpf" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" style="display:none" /> <!-- The hidden button -->
</form>
<button class="action btn btn-success">Teste</button>
```

The JavaScript:

```
$(".action").click(() = > {
    $(".ajaxForm input[type='submit']").click();
});
$(".ajaxForm").submit(() = > false);
```

So, this quick fix will work, for now. Here is the [jsFiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/ThiagoJourdan/h5q8q5mu/9/).

Answer (score 0):

3 things:

1. That is not how you use `required`.
2. You need to wrap your jQuery code in `.ready()`.
3. Move the `<button>` element inside the `<form>` and make it `type="submit"`.

**Updated Code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".action").click(()=>{
        $(".ajaxForm").submit();
    });
    $(".ajaxForm").submit(()=>false);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="ajaxForm">
    <div class="container col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                Nome
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control nome" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                CPF
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control cpf" required />
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="action btn btn-success">Teste</button>
</form>
```

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5q8q5mu/6/)

Comment: Hey, Rahul. Thing is, my button won't be inside the form. That is why he triggers the submit. And the lack of $(document).ready() is not what is doing it.

Comment: @ThiagoJourdan In that case, I would recommend using the jQuery validation plugin: http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/ Check their docs and example and you can go from there.