# If any form field in the group is filled, prompt user to fill in the other fields within the same group

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a page which allows people to refer their family or friends. This page allows up to 5 referrals, only the details of the person making the referral and the first referral are compulsory.

The form fields for the referral are Salutation, Name, Contact number, Email and Best time to call. When any one of the form field is filled, e.g. Referral_2_Name, I want to prompt the user to fill in the remaining form fields within the same group (Referral_2_Salutation, Referral_2_Contact_Number, Referral_2_Email and Referral_2_Best_Time_To_Call).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Customer Referral Programme</title>
    <meta name="title" content="Customer Referral Programme">
    <meta name="heading" content="Customer Referral Programme">
    <meta name="description" content="Customer Referral Programme">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">

    <meta name="category" content="others">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets-forms/css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets-forms/css/form.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets-forms/css/vendor/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets-forms/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets-forms/js/vendor/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets-forms/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-form o-wrapper">
        <div id="section_contact_form">

            <div class="form-alert">
                <p>All fields with (*) are mandatory.</p>
            </div>

        <form id="customer_referral" action="formprocessing.php" method="post" class="form contact-form">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="control-label col-md-12" style="color: #6d0017;"><strong>My Particulars</strong></div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="control-label col-md-4 required">Salutation</div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <select type="text" class="form-control" name="Salutation" required>
                            <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
                            <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                            <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                            <option value="Ms">Ms</option>     
                            <option value="Mdm">Mdm</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group row">
                  <div class="control-label col-md-4 required">Full Name</div>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name" required maxlength="50">
                  </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                  <div class="control-label col-md-4 required">NRIC /Passport No. </div>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Nric_or_Passport_No" required maxlength="9">
                  </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                  <div class="control-label col-md-4 required">Contact Number</div>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Contact_Number" maxlength="20">
                  </div>
            </div>                                                          

            <div class="form-group row">
                   <div class="control-label col-md-4 required">Email Address</div>
                   <div class="col-md-5">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Email" required maxlength="50">
                   </div>
            </div>


            <div class="Referral1">

                 <div class="form-group row">
                       <div class="control-label col-md-12" style="color: #6d0017;"><strong>My Referral: </strong></div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group row">
                       <div class="control-label col-md-4 required">Salutation</div>
                       <div class="col-md-5">
                           <select type="text" class="form-control" name="Referral_Salutation" required>
                               <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
                               <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                               <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                               <option value="Ms">Ms</option>     
                               <option value="Mdm">Mdm</option>
                           </select>

                       </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group row">
                       <div class="control-label col-md-4 required">Name</div>
                       <div class="col-md-5">
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Referral_Name" required maxlength="50">
                       </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group row">
                       <div class="control-label col-md-4 required">Contact Number (HP/Home/Office)</div>
                       <div class="col-md-5">
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Referral_Contact_Number" required maxlength="20">
                       </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="control-label col-md-4 required">Email Address</div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Referral_Email" required maxlength="50">
                        </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="control-label col-md-4 required">Best Time to Call
                              <span class="popovers" data-toggle="popover"><i class="fa fa-info-circle text-red"></i></span>
                        </div>                                  
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                              <select type="text" class="form-control" name="Referral_Best_Time_To_Call" required>
                                    <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
                                    <option value="9am_to_12pm">9am - 12 pm</option>
                                    <option value="12pm_to_2pm">12pm - 2pm</option>
                                    <option value="2pm_to_4pm">2pm - 4pm</option>
                                    <option value="4pm_to_6pm">4pm - 6pm</option>
                                    <option value="Anytime">Anytime</option>
                              </select>
                        </div>
                </div>              
        </div>       

        <div id="Referral2">

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="control-label col-md-12" style="color: #6d0017;"><strong>My Referral #2: </strong></div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="control-label col-md-4">Salutation</div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <select type="text" class="form-control" name="Referral_2_Salutation">
                        <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
                        <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                        <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                        <option value="Ms">Ms</option>     
                        <option value="Mdm">Mdm</option>
                    </select>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="control-label col-md-4">Name</div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Referral_2_Name" value="" maxlength="50">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="control-label col-md-4">Contact Number (HP/Home/Office)</div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Referral_2_Contact_Number" value="" maxlength="20">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="control-label col-md-4">Email Address</div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Referral_2_Email" value="" maxlength="50">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="control-label col-md-4">Best Time to Call</div>                                  
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <select type="text" class="form-control" name="Referral_2_Best_Time_To_Call">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
                    <option value="9am_to_12pm">9am - 12 pm</option>
                    <option value="12pm_to_2pm">12pm - 2pm</option>
                    <option value="2pm_to_4pm">2pm - 4pm</option>
                    <option value="4pm_to_6pm">4pm - 6pm</option>
                    <option value="Anytime">Anytime</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>      



        <div id="Referral3">
        //Referral 3 form field here. Not compulsory for users to fill in, only when they have filled in one of the form fields in this group, then prompt users to fill in the rest of the form fields within this group.
        </div>        

        <div id="Referral4">
          //Referral 4 form fields here.  Not compulsory for users to fill in, only when they have filled in one of the form fields in this group, then prompt users to fill in the rest of the form fields within this group.
        </div>

        <div id="Referral5">
          //Referral 5 form fields here.  Not compulsory for users to fill in, only when they have filled in one of the form fields in this group, then prompt users to fill in the rest of the form fields within this group.
        </div>


        <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-md-3"></div>
              <div class="col-md-9"><button id="addButton" class="btn btn-submit-contact" type="button">Add More Referral</button>
              <button id="removeButton" class="btn btn-submit-contact" type="button">Remove Referral</button>
              </div>
        </div>             


        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-3">
            <button id="btn_submit_callback_form" class="btn btn-submit-contact" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>


  </div>
        <!-- Main script files -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets-forms/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets-forms/js/vendor/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets-forms/js/vendor/jqueryvalidation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets-forms/js/form.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Bootstrap, you can add `.has-error`, `.has-success`, or `.has-warning` to the parent element of the form element you want as a requirement. The form element must have `.control-label`, `.form-control`, or `.help-block` as well. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19640789/2813224) and [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation) for details.

#### Example

```
<div class="col-md-5 .has-error">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Referral_3_Email" value="" maxlength="50">
</div>
```

#### OR

You can add the attribute `required=true` to each form element.

#### Example

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Referral_3_Email" value="" maxlength="50" required=true>
```

Comment: This is for validation of the form fields. But what i'm trying to say is, Referral 2, 3, 4 and 5 are not compulsory fields.  Only when for example, the Name for Referral 3 is filled, then there is a need to prompt the user to fill in the Salutation, Contact Number and Email for Referral 3.   Or when the Contact Number for Referral 2 is filled, then there is a need to prompt the user to fill in Salutation, Name, Contact Number and Email for Referral 2. I hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Could you make a reduced example since only a portion of the code is to be considered? Post it as a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).